# MySQL STR_TO_DATE always returns 2019

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to convert a string to a date in MySQL, but it always returns the year as 2019. Not sure why its happening.

```
SELECT STR_TO_DATE("01/01/1989","%d/%m/%Y");
```

> 2019-01-01

Comment: Cannot reproduce, this query returns '1989-01-01'  as expected (MySQL 5.6)

Answer (score 0):

Your statement is correct see example..

STR_TO_DATE("01/01/1989","%d/%m/%Y")
1989-01-01

> ```
> SELECT STR_TO_DATE("01/01/1989","%d/%m/%Y");
> ```
>
> ```
> | STR_TO_DATE("01/01/1989","%d/%m/%Y") |
> | :----------------------------------- |
> | 1989-01-01                           |
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=94dbc817a422f4c88556696430275ef8)*

If you still have the probolem see if you can make a dbfidle example that shows us the problem

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that your actual code is:

```
SELECT STR_TO_DATE("01/01/1989","%d/%m/%y");
```

which returns:

```
2019-01-01
```

because the specifier `%y` expects a 2 digit year so it returns the first 2 digits of `1989` as the year.
So change `y` to `Y`

Answer (score -1):

It doesn't look like your syntax is quite right, here's an example I've found:

`SELECT STR_TO_DATE('21,5,2013','%d,%m,%Y');`

it doesn't look like your code is separating the day, month or year so perhaps that's the problem?

[Here's the tutorial page I checked out, maybe there's more in-depth examples in here as well.](https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-str_to_date/)